# Is it safe to: Completely remove a gnome shell extension and vanilla gnome session?

Tags: 18.04

I am more familiar with pure Ubuntu vanilla gnome thereore I do the following:

1. To completely remove the gnome shell extensions from Ubuntu to do so I used this command:

   - sudo rm -r /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/
2. To install vanilla gnome session I used the following:

   - For installation

   sudo apt install gnome-session

   - For using gnome gdm environment:

   sudo update-alternatives --config gdm3.css

As a result Ubuntu will become a pure Vanilla gnome desktop, I like it but there is always sound in the back of my head say that this maybe will affect the os behavior or the upcoming the os update/upgrade.

Is it safe to do 1 & 2, and does these two point will affect the sys performance?

Looking forward to hearing from you.

Thank you in advanced

H.J

Comment: the way 0f removal 0f extension is not proper.. you can avoid this step and proceed with step 2 and later..

Comment: you can do like this for point no. 1 `sudo apt purge gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock --dry-run` and see what will go away along with that extension.. similrly for appindicators also.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're trying to accomplish. There are only 3 system extensions in `/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions`... desktop-icons, ubuntu dock, and ubuntu appindicators. Also, your local extensions are at `~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions`. Is there one in particular that you don't want/need? What actual problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Also, at the login screen, select your name, then click on the cogwheel icon, and tell me what choices you see there.